# JS-like backtick string literals

Tags: c++

Is there a syntax in c++ that is similar to this JS syntax:

```
const alpha = 5;
console.log(`alpha: ${alpha}`);
```

I want same functionality, but in c++. Does it exist?

Comment: No, symbols cannot be accessed by string representations dynamically at runtime in c++.

Comment: No. But for output to a stream (any stream, `cout` or a file-stream or a string-stream) just use the normal "output" operator `<<`? As in `std::cout << "alpha: " << alpha << '\n';`

Comment: Since c++20 you could do `std::cout << std::format("alpha: {}", alpha); << '\n';` (but that's still not equal to what you can to in js)

Comment: Links for duplicates are incorrect. This question should be reopened. As for the subject - it is really possible to implement for the language. Boils down to substrings concatenation and calling some overloads for `to_string(alpha)`. Referencing objects whithin the string by names is way cleaner than using `{}`